# Python - sqlalchemy - oracle connection fails to connect to SID

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I am trying to use `sqlalchemy` to connect to an oracle DB.  I was expecting the following to work given that it appears the exact syntax is shown in the [sqlalchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/oracle.html).

```
oracle_db = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle://user:pass@server:1521/dev')
```

but this results in the error:

> dsn = self.dbapi.makedsn(url.host, port, **makedsn_kwargs)
>   TypeError: makedsn() takes no keyword arguments

The following call initially works without the service name

```
oracle_db = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle://user:pass@server:1521')
```

But when trying to connect it fails with an error complaining that the `SERVICE_NAME` was not provided.

> ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

Oddly this works with `cx_Oracle` directly:

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass@server:1521/dev')
```

How am I supposed to connect to the specific service?

**Attempts**

I have tried to use `cx_Oracle.makedsn()` explicitly from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140902/using-oracle-service-names-with-sqlalchemy) with no luck as well.

Trying to use `?` options in the connection string

```
oracle_db = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle://user:pass@server:1521/?sid=dev')
```

works initially but when I try `oracle_db.connect()` I get the same `ORA-12504` error shown above.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the documentation at [Sqlalchemy Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/oracle.html), you should probably use the cx_oracle engine.  The connect string is:

```
oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@host:port/dbname[?key=value&key=value...]
```

with an option of service_name or sid as follows:

```
oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@host:1521/?service_name=hr
oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@host:1521/?sid=hr
```

Comment: I have tried both, the first resulted in `TypeError: makedsn() takes no keyword arguments` and the second resulted in the same `not given the SERVICE_NAME` error` when trying to `connect`

Comment: You might actually try using a tns_names entry.  Try looking at: [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html] for an example.

Comment: The tns_names may work but I don't have those readily available.  I don't understand why the nearly same string directly to `cx_Oracle` works but not when passed through `sqlalchemy`.

Comment: Maybe that is your answer "nearly the same"? What is the difference between the two? Why are you not using the same strings?

Comment: Because the syntax differs slightly according to the docs. See the cx_Oracle example I included above. If I use the exact same it gives the same error.

Comment: AH! Ok, so the difference between what I suggested and what you wrote was to use the "oracle+cx_oracle" at the beginning of the connect string. Did you try this? 

```oracle_db = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@server:1521/?sid=dev')```

This is your example, only with ```+cx_oracle```

Comment: Unfortunately that still results in the `ORA-12504` error when I try `oracle_db.connect()`

Comment: I'm sorry this isn't working for you. I don't have an oracle instance to attach to, otherwise I would be able to help you further.

Comment: `oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@host:1521/?service_name=hr` this one works for me...But it's pretty weird.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this connection string:

```
engine = create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://<username>:<password>@(DESCRIPTION = (LOAD_BALANCE=on) (FAILOVER=ON) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <host>)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = devdb)))")
```

It worked for me.