# Is there an elegant way to deal with an oracle connection by python in pytest?

Tags: python, oracle, pytest, fixtures, cx-oracle

I am in a project which needs to get datum from an oracle database.
The source code reaches the database by cx_Oracle.
Now I wanna find a way to make a fixture for the connection.
Is there an elegant way to make such a fixture?
Or could somebody recommend a pytest-plugin for Oracle connection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on what you are looking for?

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga, Thank you for replying. I am looking for a pytest plugin which is coded for an Oracle dababase, just like pytest-mysql.

Comment: We have a test suite (based on unittest) but nothing based on pytest yet. If you can let us know what the advantages are to using pytest (as opposed to unittest) let us know on the cx_Oracle issues page and make an enhancement request there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got a project using pytest. Maybe I should write one for the project.

Comment: Contributions are always gratefully accepted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLAlchemy for this. Just plug in your connection string into the create_engine string and create a fixture for the connection (and session) like this:

```
engine = create_engine('your connection string goes here with your login creds')

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def connection():
    connection = engine.connect()
    yield connection
    connection.close()
```

You can read more about the cx_Oracle connection engine from the SQLAlchemy docs here:
[Location](https://docs.qlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/oracle.html?highlight=oracle#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.cx_oracle)

Your create_engine might look something like this:

```
engine = create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://<username>:<password>@(DESCRIPTION = (LOAD_BALANCE=on) (FAILOVER=ON) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <host>)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = devdb)))")
```

Which was pulled from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455358/python-sqlalchemy-oracle-connection-fails-to-connect-to-sid)